# jquery form serialize() doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

Hi everyone I tried to serialize a form by his ID using jquery method serialize().

Html code:

```
<form name="structure_form" id="structure_form" method="post">
    <div id="add_sections" class="postbox add_section_box">
        <button type="button" class="handlediv button-link" aria-expanded="true"><span class="screen-reader-text">Commuta il pannello: Add section</span><span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h3 class="handle ui-sortable-handle structure_title"><span>Add Section</span></h3>
        <div class="inside">
            #CONTENT#
            &nbsp;<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large saveSections" id="save" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Js code:

```
$('.saveSections').on('click', function () {
    var serializedForm = $('#structure_form').serialize();
    $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'saveConfiguration', serializedForm: serializedForm}, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
    console.log("configuration saved");
});
```

Php code:

```
function saveConfiguration() {
    print_r($_POST['serializedForm']);
    exit;
}



   function add_section_meta_box() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "minisites") {
        $addSection = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/components/add_section_box.html');
        $addSection = str_replace('#CONTENT#', Utils::createSelect(), $addSection);
    }
    echo Utils::includeScripts();
    echo $addSection;
}
```

This is Utils::createSelect

```
public static function createSelect() {
    $sections = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'sections',
        'posts_per_page' => 10)
    );
    $html = '<select id="sections" name="item">';
    foreach ($sections as $section) {
        $html .= '<option value="' . $section->ID . '">' . $section->post_title . '</option>';
    }
    $html .= '</select><br><br>';
    $html .= '<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large addSection" id="add" value="Add">';
    return $html;
}
```

the output is empty or undefined. 
I think that the problem is the ID's form because if I change `$('#structure_form')` with `$('form')` it works fine.

Thanks in advance.

Edit(Update):

I add code in order that it works

Create custom_post_type, box, ecc (Plugin)

```
   <?php

//error_reporting(E_ALL);
//ini_set("display_errors", 'on');
/*
  Plugin Name: deaSiteBuilder
  Version: 1.0
  Description:
  Author: Giuseppe Giubaldo
  Author URI:
 */

require_once 'utils.php';
require_once __DIR__ . '/../../../vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Parser;

add_action('init', 'create_post_type');

function create_post_type() {
    register_post_type('minisites', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Minisites'),
            'singular_name' => __('Minisite'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
            )
    );
    register_post_type('sections', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Sections'),
            'singular_name' => __('Section'),
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
    ));
}

//Add default meta box 
add_action('edit_form_after_editor', 'add_section_meta_box');

function add_section_meta_box() {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type == "minisites") {
        $addSection = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/components/add_section_box.html');
        $addSection = str_replace('#CONTENT#', Utils::createSelect(), $addSection);
    }
    echo Utils::includeScripts();
    echo $addSection;
}

//Our custom meta box will be loaded on ajax 
function add_structure_meta_box($post_name) {
    $sectionStructureBox = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . '/templates/components/sectionStructureBox.html');
    $sectionStructureBox = str_replace('#ELEMENT#', strtoupper($post_name), $sectionStructureBox);
    $sectionStructureBox = str_replace('#CONTENT#', $post_name, $sectionStructureBox);
    echo $sectionStructureBox;
}

//Call ajax
add_action('wp_ajax_addStructureBox', 'addStructureBox');

function addStructureBox() {
    add_structure_meta_box($_POST['section']);
    exit;
}

add_action('wp_ajax_saveConfiguration', 'saveConfiguration');

function saveConfiguration() {
    echo $_POST['serializedForm'];
    exit;
}
```

Html pages:

sections_box

```
<form name="structure_form" id="structure_form" method="post">
    <div id="add_sections" class="postbox add_section_box">
        <button type="button" class="handlediv button-link" aria-expanded="true"><span class="screen-reader-text">Commuta il pannello: Add section</span><span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
        <h3 class="handle ui-sortable-handle structure_title"><span>Add Section</span></h3>
        <div class="inside">
            #CONTENT#
            &nbsp;<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large saveSections" id="save" value="Save">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

structure_box

```
<div id="section_structure_box" class="postbox section_box">
<button type="button" class="handlediv button-link" aria-expanded="true"><span class="screen-reader-text">Commuta il pannello: Section Structure</span><span class="toggle-indicator" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
<!--    <div class="handlediv" title="Click to toggle"><br>
    </div>-->
<h3 class="handle ui-sortable-handle structure_title"><span>Section Structure - #ELEMENT#</span></h3>
<div class="inside">
    #CONTENT#
</div>
<!--<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large remove_box" id="remove" value="Remove">-->
```

Class Utils:

```
    <?php

class Utils {

    public static function createSelect() {
        $sections = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'sections',
            'posts_per_page' => 10)
        );
        $html = '<select id="sections" name="item">';
        foreach ($sections as $section) {
            $html .= '<option value="' . $section->ID . '">' . $section->post_title . '</option>';
        }
        $html .= '</select><br><br>';
        $html .= '<input type="button" class="button button-primary button-large addSection" id="add" value="Add">';
        return $html;
    }

    public static function includeScripts() {
        $html = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . plugins_url('deaSiteBuilder/assets/css/style.css', dirname(__FILE__)) . '">';
        $html .= '<script src="' . plugins_url('deaSiteBuilder/assets/js/jquery.min.js', dirname(__FILE__)) . '"></script>';
        $html .= '<script src="' . plugins_url('deaSiteBuilder/assets/js/jquery-ui.js', dirname(__FILE__)) . '"></script>';
        $html .= '<script src="' . plugins_url('deaSiteBuilder/assets/js/plugin.js', dirname(__FILE__)) . '"></script>';
        return $html;
    }

}
```

And js code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.addSection').on('click', function () {
        var selectedSection = $('#sections option:selected').text();
        $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'addStructureBox', section: selectedSection}, function (data) {
            $('#add_sections').parent().append(data);
            console.log("section added");
        });
    });

    $('.saveSections').on('click', function () {
        var serializedForm = $('body form#structure_form').serialize();
        alert(serializedForm);
        $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'saveConfiguration', serializedForm: serializedForm}, function (data) {

        });
        console.log("configuration saved");
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you using duplicate IDs?

Comment: no, I'm not using duplicate IDs

Comment: It looks like it... Anyway, post minimalistic sample replicating your issue and check for dupe IDs using `$('[id=structure_form]').length`, if 0 or 2>, you know where is your issue. FYI, you could use `var serializedForm = $(this).closest('form').serialize();`

Comment: .length print value 0

Comment: I already tried with closest and doesn't work

Comment: Well so something else is hapenning that we cannot be aware regarding your posted infos. Maybe a plugin change your HTML markup or....

Comment: need more infos? what kind of infos?

Comment: it look like structure_form doesn't exists

Comment: A [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be enough info. Are you using any plugin that could change your HTML markup??? And if you inspect button, what is the HTML markup? Is the `form` removed or what?

Comment: I think there is a MCVE. I think that the problem is clear. Or not?

Comment: oh yes with the inspector the form is not visible but it is visible with the source page html

Comment: No it is not clear, specially because you posted `#CONTENT#` isntead of relevant content. I guess this content close the `form`, maybe invalid HTML markup, who knows...?!

Comment: and no, I'm not using any plugin that changing html markup

Comment: ok ok #CONTENT# is replace by php str_replace with a html select

Comment: I add new edit with the code

Comment: Did you add `name` attributes to all your form fields? `.serialize()` only includes elements that have a `name` attribute

Comment: Yes, select has a name and it's the only element that include name attribute

Comment: It could be because you are nesting your `form` inside an other `form` BUT it would be silly mistake...  Now provide all your HTML source code, you could paste it on a jsFiddle. BTW, still waiting for a MCVE

Comment: Can you try it under submit event ?

Comment: yes, I try with type= button and type=submit

Comment: silly mistake, what do you mean? @A.Wolff

Comment: is select created on button click event?

Comment: what is your value of ajaxurl ? for $.post(ajaxurl, {action: 'saveConfiguration',...............

Comment: @Prateik the select is created when the page is loaded.

Comment: @KuldeepPhPDeveloper value for $.post... is empty

Comment: on which page you are sending data? by post method , is it same as current page url.

Comment: no, js and php code are separated

Comment: Try `$("form[id='structure_form']").serialize();`

Comment: no, it's not work @simon

Comment: _"oh yes with the inspector the form is not visible but it is visible with the source page html"_ so there is something that is updating the DOM removing the form. This way your JS will never work.

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
    $('.saveSections').on('click', function () {
        var serializedForm = $('#structure_form').serialize();

serializedForm.push({name: 'action', value: 'saveConfiguration'});
        $.post(ajaxurl, serializedForm, function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
        console.log("configuration saved");
    });
```

Comment: the page on which you are posting put this code at first line

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_REQUEST);
die;

Comment: again, alert print 0

Comment: var serializedForm = $('body form#structure_form').serialize();

first add any hidden input with name and value and test

Comment: sorry but no, it's the same. now alert is empty. Maybe there is a problem with my own code... do you think?

Comment: please update the question with full current code, so I can find where you are doing thing wrong, coz at my end it works fine with this hidden input as currently form didnt have any inputs

Comment: the problem is nested form. Wordpress has own form that include entire page